# AI chat web app

Tags: android, chat, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, whatsapp

I am new to artificial intelligence but I have 5 years of experience in traditional programming, my question is that programming language or what framework would you recommend to make the following application .
A chat bot that learns from what people write to you, for example:
 Day 1:
let's say I tell the chat bot that I went to the doctor and he told me I have to take 5 pills a day 
Day 2: I write to the chat bot hello and we have a little conversation and then the bot chat asks me how to follow health or if I already take my pills

Can it be done ? , I want you to be able to tell him things and let him remember them and we can keep talking about it or when I ask something from the past he can remember it.

The second application is only to feed the database of the first application.
An android application that takes all the messages I send and save them to a database, for example:
When I send a message by whatsapp this app immediately save the message and the name of someone send it to you and so with facebook messenger , so that the chat bot learns from the way I write and respond with certain people and that it creates a base  memory data.

Anyway what I want is to become me and my way of speaking, in a chat bot, in addition and saving the conversations that I have with all the other people in a database so that they can then continue talking to him and that he learns new things with each person who Write.

This project that I have in mind is so that when I die, my family can keep talking to me